# Trace not working on Python TKinter checkbutton control

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I'm doing my own tweak on the technique from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860675/variable-size-list-of-checkboxes-in-standard-tkinter-package), using a canvas vs. a text widget to get some finer control over the scrolling behavior.  My code appears below.

All is working as I want it but for some reason the `trace` I'm using to track the checkbutton values isn't working.  No errors of any kind show up in the console window.  But I don't get the expected printed message (from `_cbWasClicked`) when I click one any of the checkbuttons.  As best I can tell the method is just never invoked.

I know it's got to be a simple and obvious bug but I'm stumped.  I've used `print` statements to confirm that the 100 `IntVars` get instantiated as expected.  Then I deliberately misspelled the method name in the `.trace` and this time it generated an error.  So when I yank those diagnostic tweaks all **should** be working.... it just **isn't.**  Can someone tell me what I'm missing?

Environment is Python 2.7 on Windows 7.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class myCheckList(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = root
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical")
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=200, height=290, 
                                relief=tk.GROOVE,bd=3,
                                scrollregion=(0,0,0,2020),
                                yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set,
                                yscrollincrement=20)
        basecolor = self.canvas.cget('background')
        self.vsb.config(command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=tk.NSEW,padx=(0,0),pady=0)
        self.vsb.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=tk.NS,padx=(0,0),pady=0)
        for i in range(100):
            cbv = tk.IntVar()
            cbv.trace('w',self._cbWasClicked)
            cb  = tk.Checkbutton(self, background=basecolor,
                                 variable=cbv,
                                 text="Checkbutton #%s" % i)
            self.canvas.create_window(5,20*i+5,anchor=tk.NW,window=cb)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<MouseWheel>',
         lambda event: self.canvas.yview_scroll(-1*event.delta/120, tk.UNITS))

    def _cbWasClicked(self,*args):
        print 'checkbox clicked'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    myCheckList(root).grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=tk.W,padx=0,pady=0)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, after much wrestling and experimenting.  It turns out that the `trace` works perfectly when I add a couple of lines to the class's `__init__`:

```
self.status = []
```

...and then, inside the loop...

```
    self.status.append((cb,cbv))
```

...which tells me that garbage collection is the culprit.  By creating a list and storing the object references in it, they couldn't be garbage-collected and so the `.trace` remains effective.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you should prepend `self.` to `cbv` and `cb` within the FOR cycle.
Secondly, even then it is going to work only for the very last checkbox, because with each iteration you overwrite the variable `cbv` again and again.
As a workaround I used a list of vaiables (`self.li`) generated one step before the cycle. This way you can link each checkbox to its own variable:

```
self.li = ['cbv' + str(i) for i in range(100)]
        for i in range(100):
            self.li[i] = tk.IntVar()
            self.cb  = tk.Checkbutton(self, background=basecolor,
                                 variable=self.li[i],
                                 text="Checkbutton #%s" % i)
            self.li[i].trace('w', self._cbWasClicked)
            self.canvas.create_window(5,20*i+5,anchor=tk.NW,window=self.cb)
            ...
```

This code worked fine for me.
You will then need to identify each checkbox somehow. You can do it using the internal variable `name` which is passed as the first param to the `callback` function in the `trace` method ([What are the arguments to Tkinter variable trace method callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690463/what-are-the-arguments-to-tkinter-variable-trace-method-callbacks)):

```
def _cbWasClicked(self, name, *args):
        print('checkbox %s clicked:' % name)
```

In the output you'll get something like this:

```
checkbox PY_VAR10 clicked:
checkbox PY_VAR99 clicked:
checkbox PY_VAR0 clicked:
```