# Direct entry in the SpinBox

Tags: tkinter

Consider this simple code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def update_label():
    my_label.config(text = my_var.get())


my_label = Label(root, text = "?")
my_label.pack()
my_var = IntVar()
Spinbox(root, from_ = 1, to = 10,  textvariable = my_var, command = update_label).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The documentation at [New Mexico Tech](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/spinbox.html) states that:

> The user can also enter values directly, treating the widget as if it
>   were an Entry.

However if I enter a value directly in the SpinBox from the above code, it does not trigger the command callback.

Further, I can enter any value in the SpinBox widget despite the fact that I have restricted its `-from` and `_to` values between 1 and 10.

**My questions:**

1. Can I do something so that a direct entry in spinbox triggers the command callback ?
2. Can I restrict the value that can be entered directly within 1 and 10 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a trace to `my_var` which can be called everytime the value changes.  For a little more information, see:

[What are the arguments to Tkinter variable trace method callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29690463/7432)

You can do data validation by using the `validate` and `validatecommand` attributes of the spinbox. It works exactly the same as with the Entry widget, which is covered here:

[Interactively validating Entry widget content in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4140437/interactively-validating-entry-widget-content-in-tkinter/4140988#4140988)