# Python tkinter trace error

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, trace

I'm trying to write a GUI for my code. My plan is to use tkinter's `StringVar`, `DoubleVar`, etc. to monitor my input in real time. So I found out the `DoubleVar.trace('w', callback)` function. However, every time I make the change I get an exception:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda2\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1542, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I have no idea what's going wrong. I'm using python 2.7 
My code is as follows:

```
from Tkinter import *
class test(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        Frame.__init__(self,master=None) 
        self.main_frame = Frame(master);
        self.main_frame.pack() 
        self.testvar = DoubleVar()
        self.slider_testvar = Scale(self.main_frame,variable = self.testvar,from_ = 0.2, to = 900, resolution = 0.1, orient=HORIZONTAL,length = 300)
        self.slider_testvar.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 5)       
        self.testvar.trace('w',self.testfun())    
    def testfun(self):
        print(self.testvar.get())

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1024x768")
app = test(master = root) 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce using Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 16.04. Everything works for me. Are you sure this is all of your code?

Comment: Change your trace to `self.testvar.trace('w', self.testfun)` to prevent execution on declarition and definition of your callback to `def testfun(self, *args):` to supply more than one argument. Links: [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-button-parameter-command-executed-when-declared), [trace callback arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690463/what-are-the-arguments-to-tkinter-variable-trace-method-callbacks).

Comment: @CommonSense Can you post you answer in the comment above as an Answer? So it can be 'accepted'?

Comment: @CommonSense, thank you very much, you saved my day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this line of code:

```
self.testvar.trace('w',self.testfun())
```

This is exactly the same as this:

```
result = self.testfun()
self.testvar.trace('w', result)
```

Since the function returns `None`, the trace is going to try to call `None`, and thus you get `'NoneType' object is not callable`

The `trace` method requires a *callable*. That is, a reference to a function. You need to change that line to be the following (notice the missing `()` at the end):

```
self.testvar.trace('w',self.testfun)
```

Also, you need to modify `testfun` to take arguments that are automatically passed by the tracing mechanism. For more information see [What are the arguments to Tkinter variable trace method callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29690463/7432)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Bryan Oakley You are the master of patience. I feel like on third of tkinter questions are exactly this problem

Comment: @Jannick: there are definitely a _lot_ of questions related to calling a function rather than providing a reference. The problem is that this is a somewhat hard concept for beginner programmers to wrap their head around.