# How can I use variable class to update Toplevel or Tk's title?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

How can I assign a variable class (`tkinter.StringVar()`, `tkinter.IntVar()`, etc.) to a Toplevel or Tk 's title text? My current code is like the following:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Untitled")

titleVar = tk.StringVar()
titleVar.set("Something")

def change_title():
    titleVar.set("Title changed!")
    print(titleVar.get())

tk.Button(text="Update", command=change_title).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Any widget that allows the use of a var will have a separate configuration option for that: `textvariable=` instead of `text=` for a Label, for example.  That's simply not the case here.

Comment: only some widgets have `textvariable=`. You could use `trace` in `StringVar` to execute function which will change title with `root.title(...)` but I don't see sense to use it if you can use `root.title(..)` directly in `change_title`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never tried, but based on the [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm), the `trace` method may do something what you need.

As the linked documentation has a "FIXME" only, I would try something like

```
def testCallback(*args):
    root.title(titleVar.get())

titleVar.trace("w",testCallback)
```

After that when someone modifies `titleVar` it should get propagated to the title. It may be refined using suggestions from [What are the arguments to Tkinter variable trace method callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690463/what-are-the-arguments-to-tkinter-variable-trace-method-callbacks)

However I have not tried any of this, and I also see that while this is what the title of your question seems to be about (and that is why I leave it here), in the description you seem to be more interested about getting notifications when someone else changes the title.