# How to query a record without clicking on a button

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

Am trying to `query` from `sqlite3` db without clicking on the `button` with the command.So i did `event` binding to achieve that but if i have to `query` it i have to click `keybaord enter key` and also i run the function `query_record()` when the program starts to achieve this but not able to achieve the result.

I want the record to appear in the `Listbox` as soon i enter it in the `entry` widget without clicking on the `button` or `keyboard enter key`

I know it has to be kind of event binding to achieve this but don't know how to achieve that, your suggestions are welcome to achieve this.

```
import tkinter as tk
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("STATS.db")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS institution(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
name TEXT)")
conn.commit()
conn.close()


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("300x300")

List = tk.Listbox(root, width=100)
List.pack()

e1_search = tk.StringVar()
e1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=e1_search)
e1.pack()


def query_record(event=None):
    data1 = e1_search.get()

    conn = sqlite3.connect("STATS.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM institution WHERE name like ?", (data1+"%",))
    row = cur.fetchall()

    for n in row:
        List.delete(0, tk.END)
        List.insert(tk.END, n)
        print(n)
    conn.close()

query_record()

e1.bind("<Return>", query_record)

b = tk.Button(text="Search", command=query_record)
b.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How will the computer know when to run the query? If you type "a", does it do the query? What about when you type "ab", does it run the query again? Is that what you're asking -- how to re-run the query on every keystroke?

Comment: @BryanOakley when i enter `a` or `ab` in the entry it doesn't run the `querry` unless i click on the enter key or click  the button

Comment: i want the query to be run when i type in the `entry` widget

Comment: i want it be run on every keystroke

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution to have a function called every time the user types a character is to bind on `<Any-KeyRelease>`. Like the name implies, the function will be called every time the user presses and then releases any key.

```
e1.bind("<Any-KeyRelease>", query_record)
```

Another way would be to add a trace on the variable associated with the entry. The advantage to this is that it would work for other cases, such as a user pasting into the field with the mouse, or other code in your program setting the variable to an explicit value. Plus, it would *not* be called when the user presses a key such as the arrow keys.

```
def query_record(*args):
    ...
e1_search.trace("w", query_record)
```

Comment: please can you link me to site which explain this  `e1_search.trace("w"` in know i can any alphabet for this see error  when i change `_tkinter.TclError: bad operations "q": should be one or more of rwua`

Comment: @OJOE: here are some links: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm, https://stackoverflow.com/q/29690463/7432. You can't just use any letter in that first argument. The "w" stands for "write". See https://stackoverflow.com/q/29690463/7432 for more information.