# How do I pass arguments to a callback for a StringVar?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have set up an Entry widget using tkinter and am using a StringVar in order to trace any changes to it. However, when I try to use the callback function, I find that I am unable to pass any arguments to it.

Here is what I have tried:

```
hpstring = StringVar()
hpstring.trace("w", hptrace)
hpstring.set("0")
hpbox = tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=hpstring)
hpbox.pack()

def hptrace(*args):
    print(hpstring)
```

This fails because hpstring is not defined.

```
hpstring = StringVar()
hpstring.trace("w", hptrace(hpstring))
hpstring.set("0")
hpbox = tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=hpstring)
hpbox.pack()

def hptrace(*args):
    print(hpstring)
```

This also somehow fails.

```
hpstring = StringVar()
hpstring.trace("w", lambda hpstring: hptrace(hpstring))
hpstring.set("0")
hpbox = tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=hpstring)
hpbox.pack()

def hptrace(*args):
    print(hpstring)
```

This time, it fails because "() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given".

Is there any way to have my callback function (hptrace) take hpstring as an argument?

Comment: You can't pass `hptrace` as an argument to `hpstring.trace` before you define it.

Comment: basically what chepner is trying to say is put 
`def hptrace(*args):
    print(hpstring)` before instead of after in the code in the 1st part and try it

Comment: This doesn't have any effect with any one of the options I have tried. I still get the same errors if I put the second part of my code before the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to have my callback function (hptrace) take hpstring as an argument?

You can use [lambda](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/expressions.html#lambda) or [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial). The important thing to remember is that [the function called by the trace is called with three arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29697307/7432), so whatever command you give to `trace` needs to accept those three arguments.

Using `lambda`, your code should look something like this if you want to send only `hpstring` to `hptrace`:

```
hpstring.trace("w", lambda var_name, var_index, operation: hptrace(hpstring))
```

Note: you need to define `hptrace` before you attempt to use it, which the code in your question fails to do.