# How to disable entrybox when it's empty in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to get a button to be disabled when the entrybox is empty and enabled when I type in something.

this is a part where the button and the entybox is.

```
self.description = tk.StringVar()
self.entry_ds = ttk.Entry(self, width=25, 
                          textvariable=self.description)
self.entry_ds.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=13, pady=4)
self.entry_ds.focus()

self.co_button = ttk.Button(self, text='Confirm', command=self.on_press_ds)
self.co_button.grid(column=0, row=2, pady=4)

def on_press_ds(self):
    description = self.description.get()
    if description:
        self.master.listbox.insert('end', description)
    self.destroy_ds()
    self.destroy()
```

I've tried using

```
if not self.description.get():
    self.co_button['state'] = 'disabled'
```

and was able to get the entrybox disabled when it's empty, but I was unable to get enabled when I typed in something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to add a trace on the related variable. Within the trace you can change the state of the button based on the current value.

First, define a function to be called by the trace:

```
def on_entry_trace(self, *args):
    new_state = "disabled" if self.description.get() == "" else "normal"
    self.co_button.configure(state=new_state)
```

Next, create the trace and force it to be called to set the initial state. You would do this in the same function that creates the variable.

The first argument to `trace` tells tkinter when to call the associated function. `"w"` says to call the function whenever the variable is written to (ie: the value changes). The second argument is the function to be called.

```
self.description.trace("w", self.on_entry_trace)
self.description.set("")  # initialize the state
```

Once that is set up, the function will be called whenever the value of the entry widget changes.

For more information on what the arguments to a function called by trace see [What are the arguments to Tkinter variable trace method callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690463/what-are-the-arguments-to-tkinter-variable-trace-method-callbacks)

Effbot has a decent write-up of the variable traces, including information about traces, on the page [The Variable Classes (BooleanVar, DoubleVar, IntVar, StringVar)](http://www.effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)

Comment: I added your code. But for function ```on_entry_trace``` pycharm says  parameter```*args``` is not used. And gives me errors like ```Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\82104\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\82104\PycharmProjects\Macro\GUI.py", line 256, in on_entry_trace
    self.co_button.configure(state=new_state)
AttributeError: 'Description' object has no attribute 'co_button'```

Comment: ```co_button``` is in class ```Description``` I don't understand why it's not attributed.

Comment: @김상언: I can't help you with that -- it's all code that you didn't show in your question. As for pycharm, it's telling the truth: `*args` is not used. However, the arguments are required because the trace will send parameters to the function.