# Tkinter Trace passes string not frame

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am having some issues with the trace method. I am trying to build a form which can change depending on the first option.

MCVE:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import Calendar, DateEntry
root = Tk()

def new_client_window_2(event=None, w=None, fn=None, on=None, sn=None, dob=None, ge=None, ctype=None, *args):
    print(type(w))
    children = w.winfo_children()
    for child in children:
        child.pack_forget()
        child.destroy()
    typeF = Frame(w, padx=10)
    typeF.pack(fill=X, expand=1)
    Label(typeF, text="Gender:", bg="white", width=10).pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, expand=1)
    tyOPTIONS = [None, "School", "Private", "NHS", "YOT", "Other"]
    typeE = StringVar(typeF)
    print(ctype)
    if ctype != "None":
        typeE.set(tyOPTIONS[tyOPTIONS.index(ctype)])
    else:
        typeE.set(tyOPTIONS[0])
    typeD = OptionMenu(*(typeF, typeE) + tuple(tyOPTIONS))#, command=lambda e=Event(), w=window, f=fn, o=on, s=sn, d=dob, g=ge, t=typeE.get(): self.new_client_window_2(e, w, f, o, s, d, g, ctype=t))
    typeD.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, expand=1)
    typeE.trace("w", lambda e=Event(), w=w, f=fn, o=on, s=sn, d=dob, g=ge, t=typeE.get(): new_client_window_2(event=e, w=w, fn=f, on=o, sn=s, dob=d, ge=g, ctype=t))

def new_client_window(event):
    window = Frame(root, padx=5, pady=5)
    window.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
    fnameF = Frame(window, padx=10)
    fnameF.pack(fill=X, expand=1)
    onameF = Frame(window, padx=10)
    onameF.pack(fill=X, expand=1)
    snameF = Frame(window, padx=10)
    snameF.pack(fill=X, expand=1)
    dobF = Frame(window, padx=10)
    dobF.pack(fill=X, expand=1)
    genderF = Frame(window, padx=10)
    genderF.pack(fill=X, expand=1)
    Label(fnameF, text="First Name:", bg="white", width=10).pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, expand=1)
    fname = Entry(fnameF)
    fname.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, expand=1)
    Label(onameF, text="Other Name(s):", bg="white", width=10).pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, expand=1)
    oname = Entry(onameF)
    oname.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, expand=1)
    Label(snameF, text="Surname:", bg="white", width=10).pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, expand=1)
    sname = Entry(snameF)
    sname.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, expand=1)
    Label(dobF, text="DOB:", bg="white", width=10).pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, expand=1)
    cal = DateEntry(dobF, width=12, background='darkblue', foreground='white', borderwidth=2)
    cal.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, expand=1)
    Label(genderF, text="Gender:", bg="white", width=10).pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, expand=1)
    geOPTIONS = [None, "Male", "Female", "Other"]
    genderE = StringVar(genderF)
    genderE.set(geOPTIONS[0])
    genderD = OptionMenu(*(genderF, genderE) + tuple(geOPTIONS))
    genderD.pack(side=LEFT, fill=X, expand=1)

    Button(window, text="Next", command=lambda e=Event(), w=window, f=fname, o=oname, s=sname, d=cal, g=genderE: new_client_window_2(event=e, w=w, fn=f, on=o, sn=s, dob=d, ge=g, ctype=None)).pack()

new_client_window(Event())
root.mainloop()
```

as you can see i need to pass some variables into this function from the previous section of the form (static form), then when "ctpyeE" is changed to one of the options i need to re-run the same function but this time know what ctpyeE is set as. I can then use that to adjust the rest of the form.

The error i am getting is from w.winfo_children(), w is the frame i am using to hold the form, however once ctypeE changes and the trace runs it changes its self to an empty string.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Scott\Desktop\patient\caseload.py", line 892, in <lambda>
typeE.trace("w", lambda e=Event(), w=w, f=fn, o=on, s=sn, d=dob, g=ge, t=typeE.get(): self.new_client_window_2(event=e, w=w, fn=f, on=o, sn=s, dob=d, ge=g, ctype=t))
  File "C:\Users\Scott\Desktop\patient\caseload.py", line 877, in new_client_window_2
children = w.winfo_children()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'winfo_children'
```

I am assuming the Trace function is setting its own variables in the function but i can't find any documentation on what these variables are so i can account for them.

Notes:

self.tku is my own class, cFrame and cButton are just Frame/Button with pack() added to make it a single line, it should be easy to adjust for those.

fn, on, sn, dob and ge are all Entry Widget objects. and w is the Frame that holds the form.

Comment: Have you done any debugging to verify that `w` is what you think it is? Can you please create a [mcve] so we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: @BryanOakley I know what w is, the issue is what it is, is wrong. It should be a Frame but after trace it becomes a String. This only Happens after the trace event, despite it not being changed at all. I have added the MCVE as you suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you're using the trace incorrectly.

When you create a variable trace, the function you associate with the trace will be called with three positional arguments (see [What are the arguments to Tkinter variable trace method callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29690463/7432)).  Thus, when your lambda is called, `e` is going to be set to the first positional argument, `w` is going to be set to the second positional argument, and `f` is going to be set to the third.

A simple solution is to make sure your lambda accepts these parameters before the named arguments:

```
typeE.trace("w", lambda name1, name2, operation, e=Event(), w=w, ...etc)
```