# Tkinter: OptionMenu causing 'NoneType' trace error

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

So I'm trying to use an OptionMenu to switch between a list of items that are drawn on a window. I'm able to do this by tracing the OptionMenu's variable and handling the drawing in the trace callback function. This all works beautifully when the code first executes with a default value for the variable. However, as soon as I make a selection with the OptionMenu, I receive this error:

```
    Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\NotActuallyMyRealName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I've narrowed the problem down to the OptionMenu and the trace callback. I actually stripped the script down to the point where it's basically the OptionMenu example in Tkinter's documentation, and I'm *still* getting the same error.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def callback():
    print("var:" + var.get())

var = StringVar()
var.set("A")
var.trace("w", callback())
op = OptionMenu(root, var, "A", "B", "C")
op.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Again here, the callback function DOES execute once with the default var set at "A", but changing var with the OptionMenu throws a TypeError, even if I try to change it back to "A". I can't see what could be causing this with the code stripped down to this point. Is the OptionMenu function in Tkinter simply no longer working?

Comment: You're calling `callback` when you do this: `var.trace("w", callback())`. Just pass the function name.

Comment: Also `def callback(*args):...`. For why you need to do this, read [What are the arguments to Tkinter variable trace method callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690463/what-are-the-arguments-to-tkinter-variable-trace-method-callbacks).

Comment: Thanks! Weird none of this is mentioned in the documentation I could find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

When you call a function in trace, you should call the function by just its name. However, in trace, it passes three arguments to the function (you don't need them for your purpose: see [What are the arguments to Tkinter variable trace method callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690463/what-are-the-arguments-to-tkinter-variable-trace-method-callbacks) for details). So you can define a lambda function to have 3 dummy arguments and call your callback function.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def callback():
    print("var:" + var.get())

var = StringVar()
var.set("A")
var.trace("w", lambda x,y,z: callback())
op = OptionMenu(root, var, "A", "B", "C")
op.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Or you can also define your callback function with three dummy arguments:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

def callback(a,b,c):
    print("var:" + var.get())

var = StringVar()
var.set("A")
var.trace("w", callback)
op = OptionMenu(root, var, "A", "B", "C")
op.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Both approaches should work.

Comment: Thanks! I finally got this function to work using dummy arguments! Never would have concluded that on my own.