# Insert string to tkinter text widget from other thread

Tags: python, tkinter

I've read at least 25 similar questions on this site, and I simply cannot get this working.

As it stands i'm just trying to build a simple chat app with a client and server. The GUI will be running on a separate thread to the logic to ensure things stay fluid and don't lock up. I've trimmed most of the logic out of the code to isolate the problem

```
import socket, csv, datetime, tkinter as tk, threading
from tkinter import ttk

interface = tk.Tk()
test = tk.StringVar()
test.set("String Var Test")

class serverInterface():
    def __init__(self, interface):
        global test
        self.messageLog = tk.Text(interface, height=10, state="disabled", yscrollcommand="scrollBar.set")
        self.scrollBar = ttk.Scrollbar(interface, command=self.messageLog.yview).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="nsew")
        self.messageLog.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)
        test.trace("w", serverInterface.guiUpdate(self))

    def guiUpdate(self):
        self.messageLog.insert(tk.END, test)


class server():
    def __init__(self):
        global test
        print("Server thread")
        while True:
            test.set("Updated from server object")


interface.title("Server")
serverInterface = threading.Thread(target=serverInterface(interface)) #Create serverInterface object
server = threading.Thread(target=server, daemon=True) # Create server object
server.start()
interface.mainloop()
```

This results in the console being spammed with `Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__ return self.func(*args) TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`
I've also tried to make use of Queue() as I've seen others suggest, but that just results in a different set of errors and I feel using StringVar() is probably the better way of doing this.

I appreciate that there's probably some lines in this code that don't need to be there, they're just leftovers from all the different attempts at bodging it :/

Any solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the full stack trace? Which line of code is throwing the error?

Comment: This isn't doing what you think it does: `test.trace("w", serverInterface.guiUpdate(self))` - it's _immediately_  calling `serverInterface.guiUpdate(self)`.

Comment: @BryanOakley Updated my question with the full error. Whilst it doesn't point it a line in my code, I know by process of elimination that line 14 is the culprit

Comment: How are you counting lines? Line 15 is a blank line.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yeah I meant 14 my bad, I have 2 blank lines in my program which aren't in my post so my IDE shows 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're asking about is due to this line:

```
test.trace("w", serverInterface.guiUpdate(self))
```

That line is functionally identical to this:

```
result = serverInterface.guiUpdate(self)
test.trace("w", result)
```

Since `guiUpdate(self)` returns `None`, you're asking tkinter to call `None`. Hence the error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`

The `trace` method must be given a callable (ie: a reference to a function). In this specific case you need to use `self.guiUpdate`.

The trace will [automatically pass arguments to the function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690463/what-are-the-arguments-to-tkinter-variable-trace-method-callbacks), so you need to properly define the function to accept those arguments. You also have a bug where you're trying to insert an object (test) in the text widget rather than the text contained in the object.