# "TypeError: <lambda>() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 3 were given" Lambda expression in Python. StringVar Trace, Function with parameters

Tags: python, tkinter

I write a simple lambda function callback when I enter something into entry with the following code:

```
self.myEntryWidget[0].trace('w', lambda frozen_command=self.getMiniumTokenReceive: frozen_command(b_index))
```

And the callback function is:

```
def getMiniumTokenReceive(self, b_index: int, *args):
    price = self.myEntryWidget[b_index].get()
    print(price)
```

But it gives an error

```
<lambda>() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 3 were given.
```

Is there anyway that I can pass a function with parameters as a callback into my StringVar trace ?

Comment: When you `trace` a widget, tkinter passes 3 args by itself onto the callback.

Comment: A function passed to `.trace()` *will* be called with three parameters.  You defined your lambda to have only one parameter - and you don't actually want that to actually receive a passed parameter, as it's just a trick to capture a value at definition time.  So you need to use something like `lambda x, y, z, frozen_command=...` to accept and ignore those incoming parameters.

Comment: Try something like `def getMiniumTokenReceive(self, b_index: int)` and `lambda *args, frozen_command=self.getMiniumTokenReceive: frozen_command(b_index))`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/29690463/7432

Comment: The solution by Delrius Euphoria work fine. Thanks