# Checkbuttons within a scrolling Text "spill over" the top border

Tags: python-2.7, text, checkbox, tkinter

I'm working on a scrolling list of `Checkbuttons` using the technique from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860675/variable-size-list-of-checkboxes-in-standard-tkinter-package).

I've noticed that the created windows within the `Text` widget will sometimes "spill over" the top and bottom borders of the widget itself:

[image]

Obviously it doesn't stop the widget from doing its job, but it just looks sloppy, and I tend to be picky about such things.

Tweaking the height of the widget can reduce the instances of it, but doesn't stop it from happening. The `pady` setting doesn't help either, as it is only applied to the absolute top and bottom of the entire contents (vs. the currently-visible portion).

I even tried switching to a `Canvas` instead of a `Text` widget, but the same spillover occurs, even when I use `yscrollincrement` to gain full control over the scrolling behaviour.

Is this just a limitation of Tkinter, or is there some other setting or a clever approach that I'm missing?

In case it matters, my environment is Python 2.7.6, on Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the borderwidth of the Text widget to zero. If you still want the `"sunken"` look, you can configure the outer frame.

Comment: The phrase "outer frame" was the key here -- I wasn't using anything to frame-in the text widget.  I did end up switching to a Canvas widget instead (configured with `tk.FLAT` relief), but put it inside a Frame widget configured with `tk.GROOVE` relief). The edges are firmly defined now with no spillover.